# Electric garage door (Garador Garamatic 20) won't 'learn'

Tags: garage-door-opener

Possibly a very specific question only related to people with experience of Garador electric garage door openers.

My garamatic 20 failed today. One of the wheels in the up and over door came out of alignment. I’ve fixed this, but now the Garamatic 20 fails to complete setup. I did a factory reset (after trying other options). I select the garage door type (1), and then it briefly displays L and then an 8 with a flashing period. The instructions say:

“The operator has been blocked for the control elements and a travel command was given”.

The advice is:

- “Release the operator for the control elements.”
   
  I don’t know what this means. I disconnected the whole system from the belt to check that there wasn’t any obstruction. Even disconnected, I still get this error message.
- “Check the connection of the IT 3b.”
   
  I’ve disconnected the push switch, and the infrared sensor. It made no difference.

To me it seems like it noticed an obstruction when trying to open (which I think was the misaligned door). It now won’t allow me to proceed to set up the door.
 
Do you have any advice and / or suggestions for how I can fix this?

Comment: A link to the instruction manual would be most helpful as that is an uncommon brand. Have you called the manufacturer's help line to see if they can help you through the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a broken operator. I disconnected it from the garage and tested it standalone and the behaviour was the same.

I spoke with the manufacturer and they said that error code 8 generally means irreparable failure.

There seems to be a new high pitched noise when it's running. I took it apart to see if I could see any obvious component failure, but couldn't. I also tried to disconnect different parts to see if I could get rid of the noise and have decided / deduced / guessed that there's a failure on the power supply.

Unfortunately the manufacturer don't supply spares, and given that it's not obvious what has failed I have up and bought a new operator.